# How can i link a mysql database to handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, symfony, handsontable

I'm working on a symfony project and I decided to use handsontable. However, I don't understand at all how to save data entered in handsontable because I'm new to all this.
I tried to redo the example but without success.
Could someone explain me how to do it?
Thanks in advance

https://handsontable.com/docs/saving-data/#saving-changes-using-a-callback

Comment: Do you have server-side implementation in symfony to store the data? You need some endpoint to which the data can be posted from Handsontable, then following example code should work fine.

Comment: I think you need to add more code for others to see what you have tried. Just saying I don't know how to do it isn't enough.